# Property '...' is declared but never used

Tags: angular, tslint, unused-variables

I have many unused params for my functions and constructors, usualy, an underscore does the trick

1) but here I still get the error message

I tried this (or adding an underscore)

```
/* tslint:disable-next-line:no-unused-variable */
constructor(private el: ElementRef) {  }
```

with no luck

2) how do we deal with parameters that are only used in the templates, such errors will be triggered ?

I have to console.log to faint using a variable

thanks

Comment: nobody ? come on, I even have to console.log(password) on my login forms to get rid of this issue...this really renders angular anti-secure

Comment: You don't have to `console.log()` to fake use a variable, just do something like `() => this.el;`.

Answer (score 3):

Just set your variable as public

```
constructor(public el: ElementRef) {  }
```

Source : https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/3094

Answer (score 1):

There are could be two reason for this tslint error(Property '…' is declared but never used
)

1. Either variable is getting used in HTML in that case to fixed it use public

   constructor(public el: ElementRef) {  }
2. If variable is getting used only in constructor, hence without this keyword to fix this use just remove public/private

   constructor(el: ElementRef) {  }

When we inject this way we will not be able to use it in class other than constructor.

I got very good explanation from 
[Constructor params used without the "this." are marked as unused.](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/3150)
 and [stop-manually-assigning-typescript-constructor-parameters](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2013/04/stop-manually-assigning-typescript-constructor-parameters/)

Answer (score 0):

Set this in your tslist.json

```
"noUnusedLocals": false,
"noUnusedParameters": false
```

Comment: exactly what I wanted to avoid